# Inline TeX Input renders wrong characters / symbols

Tags: bugs, text, latex, mac-os-x, text-formatting

**Bug introduced in 12.2, fixed in 13.0.**

---

As you may know, you can write TeX within a cell with `CTR`+`$` and press `RETURN` to get it rendered. This is known as `Inline TeX Input` and can be manually done with `Insert->Inline TeX Input`

So, I wanted to represent something with it in a Styled Notebook and needed both `\lfloor` and `\rfloor` from TeX. I wrote them in the Inline TeX Input and hit `RETURN` to get them rendered, the problem is that the rendered symbols are not the correct ones.

- `\lfloor` shows as |> when it is supposed to render as $\lfloor$
- `\rfloor` shows as $\lfloor$ when it is supposed to render as $\rfloor$

Later that, I tried to use `\lceil` and `\rceil` but both were rendered wrong as-well

- `\lceil` shows as $\rfloor$ when it is supposed to render as $\lceil$
- `\rceil` shows as $\lceil$ when it is supposed to render as $\rceil$

Look:

1. Here I'm in the Inline TeX Input mode within a Cell with Text Format
   [image: Here I'm in the Inline TeX Input mode on a Text Cell]
2. When I press `RETURN` I get wrong symbols rendered. I expected $\lfloor n \rfloor$
   [image: When I press enter I get wrong symbols rendered]

And also look:

1. I want left and right ceil symbols
   [image: Here I'm in the Inline TeX Input mode within a Text Cell]
2. I hit `RETURN` to render the TeX input and wrong symbols are shown. I expected $\lceil n \rceil$
   [image: When I press enter I get wrong symbols rendered]

It doesn't matter what the cell format is (Code/Text/Title/etc), the font or the file type (Styled Notebook/Notebook/etc), it's always rendering wrong symbols.

I'm not a math expert tbh but I am pretty sure this is wrong TeX rendering. How can I fix it?

I already tried totally reinstalling Mathematica, problems still exists.
Mathematica: 12.2.0.0 - OS: macOS Big Sur 11.2.1

Edit: Mathematica 12.3.0 is out and this still happens

Edit: Mathematica 12.3.1 is out and this still happens

Edit: As mentioned by Валерий Заподовников, this has been fixed on Mathematica 13.0.0

Comment: Can you provide a bit of context? Where are you writing these commands exactly?

Comment: @MarcoB - I improved the question. Is it more clear?

Comment: @AOx0: did you report this as a bug to WRI?

Comment: @Philipp I did.

Comment: Fixed in 13.0.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by Валерий Заподовников, this has been fixed on Mathematica 13.0.0

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Mathematica 12.2 on Windows and get the same, incorrect characters.  I also noticed the \langle and \rangle are not rendering correctly, either.