# Display error when rendering LaTeX brackets

Tags: latex, fonts, rendering

There appears to be an offset error when rendering inline LaTeX in my copy of Mathematica 12.3. Entering, for example, `\langle \rangle\` gives "$]\!] \ \langle$" instead of the expected $\langle \  \rangle$. Is there anything I can do about this bug myself? Ideally without having to figure out, for example, what comes after 'rangle' and using the 'wrong' brackets in code?

Comment: Can you include the code you are actually using to render this?

Comment: No code beyond what I have above, I'm using the inline LaTeX option. It appears to be a known bug, fixed in 13.0 (...that I don't actually have yet, sigh): https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/240263/inline-tex-input-renders-wrong-characters-symbols

Comment: I also don't have 13.0, but I don't need this functionality.  I have run into these kinds of problem before, where a bug is fixed, but I don't have access to the new version.  It's frustrating!

Comment: lol, just found that myself. I suppose so; or at least given that that question hasn't had an actual fix posted other than 'update', I'm not likely to get one myself.