# Are there missing symbols in the FrontEnd's TeX input interface?

Tags: front-end, output-formatting, latex

I am trying to insert an \hbar into the Front End's interface.
[image: texinput]

but the hbar is missing:

[image: result]

I've tried to use character codes and pasting the FrontEnd's [HBar] in directly. Neither work.

Does anyone know how to get the \hbar symbol?

This is related to this [thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/240263/inline-tex-input-renders-wrong-characters-symbols) which says that some missing symbols have been fixed in 13. I am running 13, but I still get a missing symbol.

Comment: Looks like a bug. `TeXForm[\[HBar]]` results correctly in `\hbar`, but `ToExpression["\\hbar", TeXForm]` gives `\[Null]`. I am using `13.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 3, 2023)`.

Comment: Thanks @Domen, Thought so. Bummer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like some of the characters can only be exported to $\TeX$, but not imported. `TeXForm[\[HBar]]` results correctly in `\hbar`, but `ToExpression["\\hbar", TeXForm]` gives `\[Null]`.

Let's try finding other characters that have the same problem. Because some characters work as unary or binary operators, we will also try importing them as $\alpha \; \square \; \beta$.

```
$Version
(* 13.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 3, 2023) *)

Grid[#~Join~{TeXForm[#[[1]]], 
     Quiet@ToExpression[ToString[TeXForm[#[[1]]]], TeXForm, HoldForm],
      Quiet@ToExpression[
       "$\\alpha " ~~ ToString[TeXForm[#[[1]]]] ~~ " \\beta$", 
       TeXForm, HoldForm]} & /@ 
  Select[Table[{#, ToString[FullForm[#]]} &[FromCharacterCode[i]], {i,
      65535}], StringMatchQ[#[[2]], "\"\\[" ~~ __] &], Frame -> All]
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

We see that quite a few characters can be exported but not imported.

Comment: Nice spelunking @Domen!

Comment: Very surprised to see \int is missing… isn’t this the first thing people usually do with LaTeX?

Comment: @CraigCarter "int"  works. But need full expression, like this as an example `ToExpression["\\int{x \,dx}",TeXForm,HoldForm]` which gives ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvMzK.png) But if you do "\\int" on its own, it will fail ofcourse as it is not complete expression for Mathematica. ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHa6r.png)

Comment: @CraigCarter, my analysis is not thorough enough – I've just tried to import the $\TeX$ character on its own, and as a binary operator. Some characters, however, require some other syntax to be properly parsed.

Answer (score 2):

Try this alternative

```
 ToExpression["\\hslash",TeXForm]
```

[image]

Not much difference from $\Huge{\hbar}$ and some seem to prefer the first one.

Comment: I’m happy with this workaround. Thanks @Nasser.